# Reference of variable not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Will someone please tell me why the first snippet of code doesn't work and the second one does. Is it the issue of variable scoping or any other issue?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var displayNo = $(".ue-show-success").css('display', 'none');
    var displayYes = $(".ue-show-error").css('display', 'block');

    $(".somebutton").on('click', function() {
        displayNo;
        displayYes.text('some text');
    });
});
```

The above code doesn't work as expected. But below one does.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".somebutton").on('click', function() {
        $(".ue-show-success").css('display', 'none');
        $(".ue-show-error").css('display', 'block').text('some text');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement creates an object:

```
var displayNo = $(".ue-show-success").css('display', 'none');
```

It is not a callable function. You'd have to do something like this:

```
var displayNo = function() {
    return $(".ue-show-success").css('display', 'none');
}
```

You'd then call that function with parentheses, like so:

```
displayNo();
```